# This is the beginning question on Else/If function

Tags: if-statement

```
var respond = ["hello", "nothing"];
function speak() {

    if ("hey") {
        return "hello";
    }
    else if ("whats up") {
    return "nothing";
    }

}
  var check = speak("whats up");
```

It worked when I typed `speak("hey")` it returned `"hello"` but `speak ("whats up")` not did not return "nothing". Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You aren't passing any parameters to your 'speak' function. You are evaluating "hey" which is truthy - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy and so it will always follow that path.

Comment: Your not passing any parameter in the speak function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a parameter coming into the function "speak", and then you need to compare that to the text "hey". The statement if("hey") will always return true, as will any non-empty string in Javascript.

Try

```
function speak(word){
   if (word == "hey"){
       return "hello";
   }
   else if (word == "whats up") {
       return "nothing";
   }
}
```